# Bash terminal and color output

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I have a shell with colors enabled:

```
man -P cat blabla > afile
```

*somefile* contains escape characters for coloring. Now I want to output *somefile* to the terminal *with* its coloring. I tried:

```
cat afile
```

But there isn't any formatting at all. The only way I found is by using

```
less afile
```

But I don't want a pager. I just want to output the file and do not enter some interactive mode. There must be a simple command to do that, but I wasn't able to find it :)

Comment: The behavior of `cat` has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: Are you sure the escape sequences are in `afile`? By default, `man` doesn't output formatting sequences if output is not going to a terminal. See the description of the `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` envvar in `man man`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command I was looking for is called [`ul`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ul) (do underlining):

```
/usr/bin/man -P cat somecommand | ul
```

It formats the BACKSPACE escape format from [groff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_%28software%29) nicely for the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the file you created. It looks like this (when viewed in [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)):

```
LS(1)                     BSD General Commands Manual                    LS(1)

N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE
     l^Hls^Hs -- list directory contents

S^HSY^HYN^HNO^HOP^HPS^HSI^HIS^HS
     l^Hls^Hs [-^H-A^HAB^HBC^HCF^HFG^HGH^HHL^HLO^HOP^HPR^HRS^HST^HTU^HUW^HW@^H@a^Hab^Hbc^Hcd^Hde^Hef^Hfg^Hgh^Hhi^Hik^Hkl^Hlm^Hmn^Hno^Hop^Hpq^Hqr^Hrs^Hst^Htu^Huw^Hwx^Hx1^H1] [_^Hf_^Hi_^Hl_^He _^H._^H._^H.]

D^HDE^HES^HSC^HCR^HRI^HIP^HPT^HTI^HIO^HON^HN
     For each operand that names a _^Hf_^Hi_^Hl_^He of a type other than directory, l^Hls^Hs
     displays its name as well as any requested, associated information.  For
     each operand that names a _^Hf_^Hi_^Hl_^He of type directory, l^Hls^Hs displays the names
     of files contained within that directory, as well as any requested, asso-
     ciated information.
```

See the `^H`? That means backup a space. The `man` command produces [troff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff) output and then pipes that output to nroff itself to format that output for display. Troff was a text formatting program that formatted ***printed*** pages. Thus, to boldface a word, `troff` would backspace over a letter and type over it. The more times it did that, the darker the letter.

When you use `man` or `nroff` on a terminal, it understands that `B^HB` means a boldfaced `B` and will show that letter in the highlighted color of the terminal. The `less` command does the same thing.

On the other hand, your `cat` command is really displaying the file as is. When it sees the sequence `B^HB`, it displays a `B` on your screen, backs up a single space, and displays another `B` on top of the previous `B`. Since this is a terminal and not a printer, that second `B` displays on top of the same pixels as the previous `B`.

Try this (since you're on a Mac):

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1
ls > ls.txt
cat ls.txt
```

Note that this does display the color. Setting the `CLICOLOR_FORCE` environment variable forces `ls` to display a colored output ***even if it's not being displayed on a terminal***. If you look at `ls.txt` in `VI`, you'll see sequences like `[34m` and `^[[m^[[m`. This tells the ANSI terminal to set various colors, and `cat` will display those colors (unless you use the `-v` option).

In other words, your assumption is backwards. Cat is giving you a perfectly renditioned version of the file while the `less` command is futzing with the output to display the *letter-backspace-letter* sequences as boldface.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation !

Answer (score 1):

`man` doesn't actually put terminal escape sequences in its output. To make bold characters, it outputs `char <backspace> char`, and for underlines it outputs `_ <backspace> char`. Pagers like `more` and `less` recognize these sequences and translate them to the appropriate terminal escape sequences for bold and underlining.

`cat`, on the other hand, just outputs what's in the file. It doesn't know how to do terminal-specific translations. When the terminal receives a `<backspace>`, it simply backs the cursor up and overwrites it with the next character output. The result is that you get readable text without the extra markup (that's why `man` sends the underscore first when underlining -- if it did it the other way you'd just see a bunch of underlines where a word is intended).

You can see this with `od -c afile | less`. You should see lots of `\b`, but no `\e`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes it clear that the problem lies with man output format as you pointed out. I hadn't realize before that pagers where so tightly linked to groff 

Does someone know of a pager that does just dump the stream with color ?